# Get users current page when session times out

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-timeout

Lots and lots of examples out there as to how to set and redirect when the session times out. But nothing that I could find for this situation.

A typical situation where a timeout control monitors the session timeout and displays a window warning the user of that when there is 1 minute left. When the session times out, the user is redirected to a page (sessionexpired.aspx) that clears the session and displays information informing the user that they are required to login again.

I would like to log the page the user was on when the session actually timed out and do that in the code behind of the sessionexpired.aspx page.

Any help would be very welcome!

Comment: can you not use Cookies..?

Comment: Before you do the redirect to the session expired page, add a ReturnUrl parameter to the querystring with the URL of the current page (through document.URL probably). You'll need to urlencode it, but then all you have to do is test for Reqeust.QueryString["ReturnURL"]. Should work just like returning from a redirect to a login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at the [Referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer%20Referer) from the current Request object. It's usually found using this:

> Request.UrlReferrer

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of these code examples to get the current page the user is on:

```
 // Returns something like "http://www.example.com/myUrl/MyPage.aspx"
 string page = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

 // Returns something like "/myUrl/MyPage.aspx"
 string page = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

 // Returns something like "MyPage.aspx"
 string page = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

So wherever your code is to log you out when your session expires (probably in your master page), just add one of these lines.

Once you have it, you can add it as a query string parameter to your login page or you can save it in a database.

Comment: Querystring parameter gets my vote. Seems cleaner then sending it off to the DB.

Comment: @Jagd - I agree. I didn't know if he needed to know this so that he could return the user to the page they were on or if he needed it for some kind of statistical marketing thing. For example, "research has shown that 70% of our users were on page XYZ when they were automatically logged off". See what I mean?

Comment: Great answer icemanind, but the previous response allows me to get the URL in the SessionExpired page no matter where is comes from. Thanks for responding, I will keep this in mind for future needs.